# Ruby on Rails PaperClip - How to store files in another location besides S3 or the public folder

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, file, paperclip, storage

I'm experimenting with PaperClip and like it and it looks to be a good solution for our project. However, we'd like to store the uploaded files in another location on the server (ubuntu) besides the public folder and S3 is not an option. So 2 questions:

1) How to set the path and url to store uploads to another directory in ubunto besides the application root or,
2) How to perhaps store the uploaded files on another LAN server as well.

Thanks in advance to all who reply. After an exhaustive search I was surprised to only see Google results for developers only using either rails_root or S3 for storage in PaperClip. Also, if anyone recommends a better file uploading solution that will meet our needs than by all means please advise on that as well. Thanks again!

Comment: hi @user1558937.. where did you finally decide to store your files on your ubuntu server?

Answer (score 5):

You can simply pass the `:path` option to `has_attached_file` to any path you desire. The docs talk about this, here: http://rdoc.info/gems/paperclip#Storage

If you `mount` some shared LAN storage on your web servers, then you can store them there. You do need a shared filesystem location available to all your app servers, so S3 is a common and easy to setup solution.

Comment: Thanks very much for the reply. I had to create a symlink to a folder where I wanted the files to actually be stored and it works.

Comment: Thank you hgmnz, and user1558937 for pointing me to a right direction. Here is my solution: ln -s /home/<the storage for paperclip> /home/<PROJECT_DIRECTORY>/releases/20130131093054/public/system